# Where the positive and negative side of an AC adapter?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

As you see in the picture below,

I got an AC adapter and cut off the two ends but I forgot to see where the positive and negative side. I Also have no electrical equipment to test it. After that I took a small LED for a speaker so that I know if the diode is reversed or forward bias for a split second. I know that it will burnt out because of the high current. But even though if it lights for a split second and then burn, then I would know it is in forward bias and if it does not, I know it is in reversed bias. Why I am  trying to find which side is + and which side is -? The reason is because I want to charge a 12 V lead acid battery without damaging it for reverse polarity and also have no equipment to check :).

Does anyone has an idea how to check which side is - or + ?

Anyone has an idea how to check

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got a 500-1000 ohm resistor around?

Comment: Nope  I don’t have any

Comment: The 12 volts provided by that supply is not sufficient to charge a 12 volt lead-acid battery - you will need at least 13.6 volts, and 14.4 volts or so to reach full charge.

Comment: how would you know the polarity before you cut of the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a tumbler filled with tap water and add a tablespoon of table salt and mix. Put in a couple forks, separated by a couple inches with a sponge or dishrag. Put that makeshift resistor in series with your LED and it won’t likely burn out. Don’t worry about getting it backwards, most LEDs can withstand quite a bit of reverse voltage.

Answer (score 2):

A voltmeter will well you which lead is what. Otherwise, sometimes the cord will have a small 'ridge' on the + side, but that's not for certain.

An LED with a 1K or so load resistor in series can also work. But be warned that LEDs don't much like reverse polarity, you can protect it with a regular diode in parallel, wired in opposite polarity to the LED.

A lamp with a diode can work too.

Basically, a voltmeter would make your life easier.

Here's a way: prepare a container of salt water and get two small test tubes or a couple of small clear glasses. Fill the test tubes or glasses with the salt water, immerse them upside-down in the container. Run the two wires, one in each test tube. Turn on the power, watch the gases accumulate in the tubes. The one that fills quicker is H2, that's the (-) terminal.

To confirm, try lighting each tube with a match. The H2 tube should burn, while the other tube filled with O2 will not.

Here's the reaction that takes place (electrolysis):

- Oxidation at anode: 2 H2O(l) → O2(g) + 4 H+(aq) + 4e.
- Reduction at cathode: 4 H+(aq) + 4e− → 2 H2(g)

You'll see that for each O2(g), two 2 H2(g) are evolved, so there is twice as much H2 produced as O2, volume wise.

Comment: I have no voltmeter 

Comment: Either way I will buy one soon, just want to figure it out today. It is okay, thanks